# File not being found in servlet, even though obtaining path via context.getRealPath?

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets, file-io

### Synopsis

Given the following (abridged) code that lives server-side on a servlet (Tomcat is the container). This is a GWT application, though that should be irrelevant (I think).

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
String dataFilePath= context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/dir/dataFile.txt");
File dataFile = new File(dataFilePath);

TestCaseGenerator testCaseGenerator = new TestCaseGenerator(dataFile);
testCaseGenerator.generateTestCase();
```

`TestCaseGenerator` is a class from a jar in the project's `war/WEB-INF/lib` folder, that's been added to the GWT project as an external library.

### The Problem

When `testCaseGenerator.generateTestCase()` gets executed, it's unable to use `dataFile` to create a `new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(dataFile));`, a `FileNotFoundException` gets thrown.

I've verified that the `String` value of `dataFilePath` is correct and contains the proper real path to the file on the server I need to read from, as well that `dataFile` isn't `null`. I've also verified that `TestCaseGenerator` runs just fine when called from a command line, outside of this GWT application.

I'm not sure why `TestCaseGenerator` isn't able to use the `File` object I pass it, considering I'm passing it the real file path of the file. I can come up with some alternative solutions to get around this issue, but now I'm genuinely curious why it isn't able to find the file.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: could you print out dataFilePath?

Comment: What's the error message of `FileNotFoundException`? Isn't it just "permission denied"?

Comment: At least explain the reason for a down vote :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

I foolishly neglected to include the `dir/dataFile.txt` in my `build.xml`'s `war` target, so in fact the file wasn't being included in the `war` package, and thus never placed within the Tomcat container.

```
<include name="dir/**" />
```

And I also misunderstood what `context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/dir/dataFile.txt");` actual returns;. From [ServletContext javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

> Gets the real path corresponding to the given virtual path. For
>   example, if path is equal to /index.html, this method will return the
>   absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request of
>   the form http://://index.html would be
>   mapped, where  corresponds to the context path of this
>   ServletContext.

So even though `getRealPath` returns a path value, it doesn't necessarily mean the file is at that actual path.